# Apply certain autovalue keys to all SimpleSchemas

Tags: meteor, schema

I have certain keys such as createdAt and updatedAt that should be defined in all schemas. Is there a way to avoid code duplication?

I use the SimpleSchema package.

I need the following code in all of my Schemas.xxx

```
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isInsert) {
            return new Date;
        } else if (this.isUpsert) {
            return {$setOnInsert: new Date};
        } else {
            this.unset();
        }
    },
    autoform: {
        type: 'hidden'
    }
},
updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoValue: function() {
        if (this.isUpdate) {
            return new Date();
        }
    },
    autoform: {
        type: 'hidden'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sub schema & then include it in every collection, notice the `SimpleSchema` constructor is now taking an array.

```
Schema._Basic = new SimpleSchema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Created at'
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: 'Updated at',
    optional: true
  },
  }
});

Schema.Client = new SimpleSchema([Schema._Basic,
  {
    address: {
      type: String
      optional: true
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution to me. Any pros / cons to use this solution over using collection-hooks?

Comment: Do both! Create the field in your schema & insert via collection hooks. It really doesn't matter whether the data gets in manually, through an autoValue, or a collection hook. Personally, I go manual. autoValues can be buggy & there are some cases (such as preference booleans) where I don't want to trigger a change to updatedAt.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with help of this very nice package: [matb33:collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) This will add before and after hooks to your collections. So you can add createdAt and updatedAt fields like this:

For CollectionName.insert();

```
CollectionName.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    doc.createdAt = currentDate;
    doc.updatedAt = currentDate;    // could be also null if you want
});
```

So that in above exmaple is triggered always just before the insert takes effect. And this is for CollectionName.update();

```
CollectionName.before.update(function (userId, doc) {
    doc.updatedAt = new Date();
});
```

This is triggered whenever you update your collection.

Comment: Can this be more generic for all collections?

Comment: Works nicely with CollectionHooks.defaults.before.all.